# Nginx GET variable rewrite and content modification

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I've seen quite similar posts but not exactly what I'm looking for. I am trying to implement a nginx rewrite which should modify the content of a get variable. The result is always 404 not found and I cannot understand what is wrong. More specifically, I want:

**https://mydomain.tld/resellers/view.php?id=1&url=https://market.tld** to be rewritten to:
**https://resellers.mydomain.tld/view.php?id=1&url=101**

So, there are 2 modifications:

1. mydomain changes to resellers.mydomain
2. url content changes to        numeric

The config that I think should work is:

```
location ~ /resellers { 
rewrite ^/resellers/view.php?id=1&url=https://market.tld https://resellers.mydomain.tld/view.php?id=1&url=101;
}
```

Because there will be multiple combinations of links, regarding the id and url variables, would it be better to use rewrite maps? What I mean is that I want to be explicit when creating rules for the id and url variables and not use wildcards, as in more simple rewrite rules.

I hope that someone has been in a situation like this before, to shed some light.
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression of the `rewrite` directive cannot match the arguments part of the URL.

If you are attempting to redirect a single URI, use the `location =` syntax. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Assuming that there are more than one mapping for the `url` parameter, the `map` is a good solution. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $arg_url $new_url {
    default                0;
    https://market.tld     101;
}

server {
    ...
    location = /resellers/view.php {
        if ($new_url) {
            return 301 https://resellers.mydomain.tld/view.php?id=$arg_id&url=$new_url;
        }

        # URL mapping not found - what to do?
        return 404;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that the `map` block is located outside of the `server` context.